# How can I create a filter view with MOD custom formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to split a spreadsheet tab (called `main`) so to have (say) N = 3 people working on it without interfering with each other.

[image]

For the purpose, I thought to create 3 filter views, each containing rows whose `ID` modulo 3 has the same result.

In a new worksheet, this is easily accomplished with a filter like

```
 =filter(main!A2:B, MOD(main!A2:A, 3) = 0)
```

(replacing 0 with 1 or 2 to get the other IDs) so that I get (in the case of modulo = 0)

[image]

How can I achieve this with a filter view with custom condition (which is handy to share separate URL links with collaborators)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already filtering. You don't need `=filter(A:A`. `=MOD(A:A, 3) = 0` should do it instead.